# What readily available items can be used for color correction or reference?

Tags: color, white-balance, color-correction, studio-setup, low-budget

Are there any easily available things I can carry with me, that I probably have already, that I could use as a rough color reference card while taking photos with a phone?

I realize that most phones will heavily process the images themselves, but if I *needed* to have a way to reference a specific color, it would be helpful if I had something in my pocket that I could add to the photo. For instance, would a clean US $1 bill be useful as a green reference? What else could I add to this to get other colors?

I realize that I could just get a pocket sized color reference card, but that is outside the scope of my current project.

Comment: why is a color checker passport out of scope again?

Comment: @Hueco Probably out of scope because OP doesn't want to buy one.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "outside the scope of my current project". Do you mean it's too expensive? Generally you can get quite good colour by accurately setting the grey point in your images. Would you consider getting something like a WhiBal or QPcard?

Comment: US paper money would likely be a poor color reference because the security features, such as special paper, water marks, embedded security strips, reflective ink, and colored markings, change the appearance of the bills when viewed from different angles. Also, previous versions of Photoshop detected when an image contained money and would refuse to load the image. It would be extremely annoying to be unable to edit an image because money was used as a color reference.

Comment: When I first got a digital camera, there was a forum suggestion to use the frosting cup from Pillsbury cinnamon rolls for obtaining white balance.  Food grade plastics are more consistent in their production than random items you find.  Since it was semi-transparent you could also use it as a flash diffuser.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently, **PTFE white matte thread seal tape** wrapped around a white polymer eraser works well as a *white balance* reference. Photography Life has an article with examples of its use:

- [DIY: Reliable and Cheap Universal White Balance Reference Device](https://photographylife.com/diy-reliable-and-cheap-universal-white-balance-reference-device).

While better than nothing, it does *not* address *color correction* at all.  The colors you end up with are whatever the profile you're using produces.  The profiles used by some software for some cameras are clearly inaccurate.

[image: PTFE tape and polymer eraser]

Some people have made **DIY clones of color charts using color swatches**.  (I reference these particular examples because they specify the exact swatches used to create the charts.)

- Gretag MacBeth clone using Pantone swatches.
  Instructables: [DIY Color Checker](https://www.instructables.com/DIY-Color-Checker/)
- SpyderCheckr clone using Behr paint swatches ("Poverty Checker")
  YouTube: [How to make a FREE COLOR CORRECTION chart](https://youtu.be/pusFS7JmKQM)

While this approach is superior to using white balance alone, *absolute* color accuracy is not ensured because few, if any, of the swatches are exact matches for the original charts.  For instance, when using the Poverty Checker against SpyderCheckr reference data, the result is more saturated than expected.  This occurs because the patches of the SpyderCheckr are highly saturated and the grayscale patches have a blue/cyan tint.

DIY charts used with commercial reference data can still be used to ensure *relative* color consistency across multiple cameras and lighting conditions.

[image: paint swatches]
[image: color mismatch]

To improve the accuracy of DIY charts, open-source software ([Argyll](http://www.argyllcms.com/), [DCamProf](https://torger.se/anders/dcamprof.html)) can be used with swatch-specific color data to generate camera profiles.  Target colors and ΔE color difference can be searched at [Encycolorpedia](https://encycolorpedia.com/).

Even better would be to measure the color of the swatches with a tristimulus colorimeter, color analyzer, color difference meter, spectrophotometer, etc.  These devices usually cost a few times more than the charts in question, but may be considered to have paid for themselves if they are used to create multiple charts.  They can also be used to profile printers and scanners.

Answer (score 1):

Likely the Kodak Q-13 Color and grayscale guide will do this trick. Google this and you will see what it looks like. That being said, for your purpose, why not make a reference card using construction paper and school paste. You don't need a calibrated card because you will have the one you made to use as a reference. The Q-13 has been in service for years and years. Their are others, just Google this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Hum... Let's take the first step.

The most important color reference is white... or should I say gray.

You need to set up your white balance for the light illuminating your scene. You could use a white sheet of paper... but they come in many flavors. Recycled one, super bright, etc. Choose one that has a god whiteness value. The closer to 100 the better one. If it is above 100 it is probably a "fake" white.

But beyond that, no. You are fooling yourself using standard objects. The only reference that they will provide is for that color. A new green bill will be a good reference for a green bill.

Color reference cards are using standardized values so the calibration software assumes what those values should be, so they can correct them using standardized corrections on standardized points on the curves and channels...

Using common objects could be used only for optical corrections, but I would not do that.

Comment: Since he is using a phone to take pictures, I believe the OP is looking for a reference colour to use in post. So they are unlikely setting white balance for the camera (is there a phone that actually allows you to set white balance?)

Comment: www.filmicpro.com can set it up for android and io. Besides that you NEED to take a white balance image. You could set the white balance in post using that reference.